# array merge only showing one value

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have these two queries

```
 mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_Asset = "SELECT idAsset, AssetName FROM Asset WHERE idLocation = '1'";
$AssetUp = mysql_query($query_Asset, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
$array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp);

mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_DocUp = "SELECT AssetDocStand.idAsset, Asset.AssetName FROM AssetDocStand INNER JOIN Asset ON AssetDocStand.idAsset = Asset.idAsset
WHERE AssetDocStand.idDocumentStandards = '2' AND Asset.idLocation ='1'";
$DocUp = mysql_query($query_DocUp, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
$array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp);
```

One gets me all assets in the current location.  The other gets me all assets in the current location that have a document uploaded with the standard of 2.  Please note I have took out all error checking for purposes of this post.

if I print the results like so:

```
do{
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";
}while($array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp));
echo "<br><br><br>";

do{
print_r($array2);
echo "<br>";
 }while($array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp));
 echo "<br><br><br>";
```

I get the following.

```
 Array ( [idAsset] => 10000005 [AssetName] => HP ) 
 Array ( [idAsset] => 10000006 [AssetName] => HP Server ) 
 Array ( [idAsset] => 10000009 [AssetName] => HP Laptop ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000010 [AssetName] => Office Printer ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000023 [AssetName] => test ) 



 Array ( [idAsset] => 10000023 [AssetName] => test )
```

No I have been trying to output only the assets that have no document uploaded.  As you can see above this would be the first 4 assets from the first list.  Now the next thing i was going to do is to merge the arrays and then use array_unique on my new array however when I do this;

```
 $array3= array_merge($array1, $array2);
 print_r($array3);
```

All I see is the following;

```
idAsset; 10000023
AssetName; test
```

I don't understand where the other 4 assets have gone?  Can anyone help me see my mistake?  Thanks guys and gals

Comment: because the 'idAsset' key is the same in each array you are merging, all of the array data is being overwritten. I would suggest using array_push to create you additional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use `mysql_*` since those function are deprecated and will soon stop being supported. Use mysqli_* and PDO instead.

That said, you are using, and even understanding the `mysql_fetch_assoc` completely wrong. An example to get your mind pointed in the right direction could be something like this:

```
<?
  $q = mysql_query("...");
  while ($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    //do something, irrelevant
  }
  print_r($f);
?>
```

This will print out only **the last row** of your query result. That is because `mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches the row, returns it, and moves the pointer to the next row. When the loop finishes, you only have the last row in your variable. You did not realize this, because your `print_r` was **inside your loop**, so should you move it outside of the loop, you would quickly realize that you see only the last row.

Example that could work for you is something like this:

```
<?
  $q1 = mysql_query("");
  $array1 = Array();
  while ($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)) $array1[] = $f;

  $q2 = mysql_query("");
  $array2 = Array();
  while ($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2)) $array2[] = $f;

?>
```

If you do `print_r($array1);` and `print_r($array2);` after these two loops, you will see that `$array1` and `$array2` have your full resultsets. You only need to merge them afterwards, and that should do the trick.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thank you for your explanation.  Yes I'm currently updating my code to support these standards but im not quite there yet. Ok so I tried your code and when I merge my arrays that works great.  I have array one and array two together.  Now I need to remove my duplicates but when I write  $array3= array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
 print_r($array3);  I have the same problem of only seeing the 1st item from array 1

Comment: That would be whole new separate question, since you would need to provide your code and let everyone see where the error is. Also you would need to show input and expected output. Please post separate question for this problem.

Comment: will do matey.  I'll mark yours off now.  thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your first do...while loop, every iteration you overwrite the previous value in `$array1` with the next row from the database, you do not add the row to the array. So afterwards only the last row is left in the array, which is the same as the one in `$array2`. You need to make sure that `$array1` contains your entire query result, eg. like so:

```
$array1[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp);
```

Edit: Also note that the mysql_* functions are deprecated. If possible, you may want to replace them with e.g. MySQLi. That would even give you a function (`mysqli_fetch_all()`) you could use to get the entire query result in one call.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace a little change as below and check:$array1 to $array1[] and $array2 to $array2[]

```
do{
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";
}while($array1[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp));
echo "<br><br><br>";

do{
print_r($array2);
echo "<br>";
 }while($array2[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp));
 echo "<br><br><br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your code, since every time you loop your `$array1`, `$array2` holds new fetch row value from database

```
do{
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";
}while($array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp));
echo "<br><br><br>";

do{
print_r($array2);
echo "<br>";
 }while($array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp));
 echo "<br><br><br>";
```

as

```
    $firstArray = array();
    $secondArray = array();
    do{
    print_r($array1);
    array_push($firstArray,$array1);
    echo "<br>";
    }while($array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp));
    echo "<br><br><br>";

    do{
    print_r($array2);
    echo "<br>";
    array_push($secondArray ,$array2);
     }while($array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp));
     echo "<br><br><br>";

    $array3= array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray );
 print_r($array3);
```

Comment: thank you too for your reply.  I have done this and yours also works great.  However when I add the array_unique() I only get my one result again

Comment: You didn't mentioned regarding array_unique in a question. Your question was regarding array_merge

Comment: array_unique() will give you one result set since your key is same therfore it over writes its value of key. so whatever will be your last result set in array will be displayed(in your case key is `idAsset`and `AssetName`)

Comment: Yeah apologies I got carried away with the question but didnt ask fully what i needed.  I'm just creating a new question now.  Again thanks for your help.  really kind

Comment: Its okay. It happens sometimes :)